# Functions agree in first $n$ derivatives and differ in the $n+1$-th derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists $x_0\in (a,b)$ verifying $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ and$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x_0)=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}g(x_0)$$for $k=1,\ldots ,n$ and$$\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}f(x_0)\neq \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}g(x_0).$$Prove that:

- If $n$ is odd then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)-g(x)$ does not change sign for $x\in (x_0-\delta ,x_0+\delta )$.
- If $n$ is even then for every $\delta >0$ there exists $x_1,x_2\in (x_0-\delta ,x_0+\delta )$ such that $f(x_1)-g(x_1)<0<f(x_2)-g(x_2)$.

It is true for $f(x)=x^m$ and $g(x)=x^{m+1}$ with $x_0=0$, so I have the feeling this should be true for every function verifying the hypothesis, but I don't know how to prove it in general.

Comment: The moral of the answer is that Taylor's theorem indicates that $f(x) - g(x)$ looks like $(x-x_0)^{n+1}$ near $x_0$. Thus when $n$ is odd, there is no sign change, and when $n$ is even there is a sign change, as this is true of $(x-x_0)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

By linearity and the change of variables $y=x-x_0$, we have to prove that if $h=f-g$ is $n+1$ differentiable at $0$ with $h(0)= h^\prime(0) = \dots = h^{(n)}(0)=0$ and $h^{(n+1)}(0)\neq 0$ then:

- If $n$ is odd $h$ doesn't change of sign in a neighborhood of zero.
- If $n$ is even the sign of $h$ is the one of either $y \mapsto y^{n+1}$ or the one of $y \mapsto -y^{n+1}$ in a neighborhood of zero.

And this is a direct consequence of [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) which states that it exists a map $y \mapsto \epsilon(y)$ defined in a neighborhood of zero and such that $\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \epsilon(y) = 0$ with

$$h(y) = h^{(n+1)}(0)\frac{y^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + y^{n+1}\epsilon(y)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: What about $g(x)=f(x)+(x-x_0)^{n+1}$?

So $g(x)-f(x)=(x-x_0)^{n+1}$. What is the behavior of $(x-x_0)^{n+1}$ if $n$ is odd, and then if $n$ is even.